# Playframework tests pass in Intellij but not in play console

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Simple insert and update test for a table:

```
    case class Player(id: UUID, name: String, email: String)
```

with all the appropriate setup in a model object for performing inserts and finds.

Running the following test:

```
class PlayerSpec extends Specification {
  "Player" should {

    val application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration =  inMemoryDatabase("test"))

    "insert a player" in {
      running(application) {

        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()

        Player.insert(Player(uuid, "Joe Person", "joe.player@someplace.mail")) must beEqualTo(1)
      }
    }

    "Find a player by id" in {
      running(application) {
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()

        Player.insert(Player(uuid, "Jane Person", "jane.player@someplace.mail"))

        Player.findById(uuid) must beEqualTo(Some(Player(uuid, "Jane Person", "jane.player@someplace.mail")))
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I get a green bar in Intellij (both examples pass).  However, when I run this in the play console I get the following error:

```
[info] PlayerSpec
[info] 
[info] Player should
[info] + insert a player
[error] ! Find a player by id
[error]     anon$1: Configuration error [Cannot connect to database [default]] Configuration.scala:258)
 ....
```

Is this a configuration issue, or am I missing some sort of a beforeEach type call?

**EDIT**

Just adding the db code, for more reference

```
case class Player(id: UUID, name: String, email: String)

object Player {

  private val fullPlayer = {
    get[UUID]("player.id")(Utils.rowToUuid) ~
    get[String]("player.name") ~
    get[String]("player.email") map {
      case id~name~email => Player(id, name, email)
    }
  }

  def insert(player: Player) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>

      SQL(
        """
          insert into player (id, name, email) values (
             {id}, {name}, {email}
          )
        """
      ).on(
        'id -> player.id.toString,
        'name -> player.name,
        'email -> player.email
      ).executeUpdate()

    }
  }

  def findById(id: UUID) : Option[Player] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("select * from player where id = {id}").on('id -> id).as(fullPlayer.singleOpt)
    }
  }
}
```

rowToUUID:

```
object Utils {
  implicit def rowToUuid: Column[UUID] = Column.nonNull {
    (value, meta) =>
      val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
      value match {
        case uuid: UUID => Right(uuid)
        case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass + " to UUID for column " + qualified))
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is likely an issue with your db configuration in your application.conf file... How do you have it configured?

Comment: I have the following: `# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"`

Comment: Do you have any evolution that need to be run? you may tray starting play console with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true

Comment: I run it with running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase()))

Comment: @opensas: I already have that (see original code)
Secondly, Tried the `-DapplyEvolutions.default=true` flag, and that doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reuse a FakeApplication for multiple tests.

Just change

```
 val application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration =  inMemoryDatabase("test"))
```

to

```
def application() = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration =  inMemoryDatabase("test"))
```

To produce a new FakeApplication each time you call application.
It would be good style to call this function with parenthesis.

Comment: This worked in the play console, yet now fails in intellij with the error 
`Cache play already exists
net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists`

Comment: I don't have your setup to reproduce so I can only guess.
It could be that bug: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/issues/39 . Or it's a classpath like described here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/xpCrPuIDEh0/lbY-D-KanwAJ or here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/JrzkjVAV2nU. Please be really shure that one test does not use resources from another test. The Cache does not work well with multiple instantances. Do you tried "play clean-all test"?

Comment: Ok, doing this, and then adding `sequential` to the spec, it behaves the same in both Intellij and the play console.  Cheers!